# Display Amchart in Lightning component [a.hasChildNodes is not a function]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to show a chart In lighnting Component using `Am-Chart` library.Same code It works fine in vf page .

It throwing  error like:

> [a.hasChildNodes is not a function]

NOTE:

1.Component Api Version - 41.0

2.AMchart Version - 3.0 [Reference](https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js)

3. Serial Version - 3.0 [Reference](https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js)

**Component :**

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', 
                           $Resource.amcharts, 
                           $Resource.serial,
                           $Resource.light)}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.getChart}"/>

    <div id="chartdiv" class="chartdiv"></div>  
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    getChart : function(component, event, helper) {
        var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "marginRight": 70,
            "dataProvider": [{
                "country": "USA",
                "visits": 3025,
                "color": "#FF0F00"
            }, {
                "country": "China",
                "visits": 1882,
                "color": "#FF6600"
            }, {
                "country": "Japan",
                "visits": 1809,
                "color": "#FF9E01"
            }, {
                "country": "Germany",
                "visits": 1322,
                "color": "#FCD202"
            }, {
                "country": "UK",
                "visits": 1122,
                "color": "#F8FF01"
            }, {
                "country": "France",
                "visits": 1114,
                "color": "#B0DE09"
            }, {
                "country": "India",
                "visits": 984,
                "color": "#04D215"
            }, {
                "country": "Spain",
                "visits": 711,
                "color": "#0D8ECF"
            }, {
                "country": "Netherlands",
                "visits": 665,
                "color": "#0D52D1"
            }, {
                "country": "Russia",
                "visits": 580,
                "color": "#2A0CD0"
            }, {
                "country": "South Korea",
                "visits": 443,
                "color": "#8A0CCF"
            }, {
                "country": "Canada",
                "visits": 441,
                "color": "#CD0D74"
            }],
            "valueAxes": [{
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "position": "left",
                "title": "Visitors from country"
            }],
            "startDuration": 1,
            "graphs": [{
                "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
                "fillColorsField": "color",
                "fillAlphas": 0.9,
                "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                "type": "column",
                "valueField": "visits"
            }],
            "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "zoomable": false
            },
            "categoryField": "country",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "gridPosition": "start",
                "labelRotation": 45
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": true
            }

        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3rd party JavaScript libraries can contain code that is incompatible with Lightning. In particular, the Locker Service imposes restrictions on how the DOM can be manipulated. See e.g. [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).

If you use your browser's Development Tools and confirm that the variable `a` is a `SecureElement` (the wrapper that Locker Service adds) then that is a strong indicator that you have hit this problem.

Some options are:

- Change to a library that is compatible with Locker Service
- Put the chart inside a [lightning:container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_container.htm)
- Work with the library authors to make the library compatible

There is another question about amCharts not working with Locker Service already [on this site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=amcharts).